# React element not rendering when abstracted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native-mapbox-gl

Attempting to map data to create elements - elements are not appearing.
When the elements are hard coded in, (Markers) they work fine. When I attempt to abstract it, the Markers are not rendered. Codebox is below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leakey-hckm2k?file=/src/App.js

*Update*
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leakey-hckm2k?file=/src/App.js
It now enters the make marker code, but does not actually render the circles as expected or as it does when I directly call the elements.

Comment: According to @Nicholas Tower answer, change the line 136 from App.js to `MakeMarker({datum, pixelScale})`

Comment: I did that - it did not seem to fix anything. I put the changes back, as you can see now, and while it logs that I am in the marker, nothing is rendered ON the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makeMarker(datum, pixelScale) {
```

Components receive props in a single object, not as separate arguments. Additionally, custom components need to be in upper case, because lowercase JSX is reserved for built in elements like `<div>`. So do the following:

```
function MakeMarker(props) {
  const { datum, pixelScale } = props;

// Or:
function MakeMarker({ datum, pixelScale }) {
```

(Technically, you could have it be lower case on this line, and then upper case when you import it, but probably best to be consistent and use uppercase everywhere)

Comment: I made that update, but the codepen still will not render the components. Could you fork my sandbox and make the edit to get it to work?

Comment: One reason I am concerned is that my print statement, console.log("IN"), is not being logged in the console. I am not sure why

Comment: Here's a working sandbox. Where you were doing `fullData.map`, you weren't returning `<MakeMarker>` elements: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-microservice-kkjho7